# Passing HEX colors in an GET ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, get

I'm trying to pass some hex colours to a php script via an GET ajax call.  PHP doesn't seem to like the hex colours though, I've tried replacing the `#` and using `encodeURIComponent` neither of which work.

here's the js (with each `currentColors` entry being a hex color)

```
var dataString = 'designName=test&mc1='+currentColors[1]+'&mc0='+currentColors[0]+'&sp='+currentColors[2];
var strippedString = encodeURIComponent(dataString);
```

Comment: why not strip the # from the colour?

Comment: why not just omit the #? you don't really need it.

Comment: What error are you getting? Why not send the color values without the `#` and add it back (if required) on the server side?

Comment: The problem seems to be in the PHP code that uses it.

Comment: encodeURIComponent("#FFF") => "%23FFF" is a valid quey parameter value, you have a problem serverside obviously.

Comment: The function is named encodeURI*Component* for a reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent` to encode URI *components*:

```
var strippedString = 
    "designName=test" + 
    "&mc1=" + encodeURIComponent(currentColors[1]) +
    "&mc0=" + encodeURIComponent(currentColors[0]) +
    "&sp="  + encodeURIComponent(currentColors[2]);
```

Example:

```
var strippedString = 
    "designName=test" + 
    "&mc1=" + encodeURIComponent("#FF0000") +
    "&mc0=" + encodeURIComponent("#00FF00") +
    "&sp="  + encodeURIComponent("#0000FF");
// "designName=test&mc1=%23FF0000&mc0=%2300FF00&sp=%230000FF"
```

On the server-side the query string will yield:

```
// parse_str("designName=test&mc1=%23FF0000&mc0=%2300FF00&sp=%230000FF", $my_GET);
// var_dump($my_GET);

array(4) {
  ["designName"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["mc1"]=>
  string(7) "#FF0000"
  ["mc0"]=>
  string(7) "#00FF00"
  ["sp"]=>
  string(7) "#0000FF"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var strippedString = dataString.split('#').join('');
```

Then, server-side, prepend `'#'` to the parameters again.

---

`.split('#')` splits a string up into a array, at the `'#'` character:

```
var s = 'designName=test&mc1=#FF0000&mc0=#FFFFFF&sp=#FF00FF';
var a = s.split('#');
console.log(a);
//["designName=test&mc1=", "FF0000&mc0=", "FFFFFF&sp=", "FF00FF"]
```

`.join('')` then joins this array together again:

```
var s = a.join('');
console.log(s);
//'designName=test&mc1=FF0000&mc0=FFFFFF&sp=FF00FF'
```

You can also use a placeholder / replacement string in the `.join('')`:

```
var s = a.join('%');
console.log(s);
//'designName=test&mc1=%FF0000&mc0=%FFFFFF&sp=%FF00FF'
```

---

Or, like [Salman A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87015/salman-a) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13948981/1835379), use `encodeURIComponent` on the components only. (which is no doubt faster than array functions like I suggested)